# Função para duplicar vencimentos em n parcelas?

Tags: php, funções

Estou tendo problemas na criação de uma função para duplicar os vencimentos, meu cenário é o seguinte, eu quero passar para a função 3 váriaveis, sendo o valorTotal, qtdadeParcelas e primeiroVencimento e caso haja mais de uma parcela um array é criado informando os próximos vencimentos conforme segue a função que estou tentando desenvolver.

```
function DesdobraParcelas($ValorTotal, $QtdeParcelas, $DataPrimeira){
if ($QtdeParcelas > 1){
    //se a quantidade parcelas for maior que 1 declaro o array e informo a data do primeiro vencimento
    $array = array();
    $array[] = $DataPrimeira;
       for($i = 1; $i <= $QtdeParcelas; $i++){ 
       //agora dentro do array queri inserir os próximos vencimentos     incrementando de 30 em 30 dias
       $array[] =  $array[] + date('Y-m-d', strtotime('+30 days', strtotime($array[$i-1])));
       }
} else {
    //caso haja apenas uma parcela a mesma é inserida no array e retornada
    $array[] = $DataPrimeira;
}
return $array; }
print_r(DesdobraParcelas(200.00, 2, '2016-12-15'));
```

Poderiam me ajudar ou apontar outra forma de resolver este problema?
obrigado.

Comment: qual esta esta aparecendo?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Fiz alguns ajustes:

Função:

```
function DesdobraParcelas($ValorTotal, $QtdeParcelas, $DataPrimeira) {
    if ($QtdeParcelas > 1) {
        //se a quantidade parcelas for maior que 1 declaro o array e informo a data do primeiro vencimento
        $array = array();
        $val_parcela = $ValorTotal / $QtdeParcelas; // calcula o valor da parcela
             
        $array['data'][] = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($DataPrimeira));
        $array['valor'][] = $val_parcela;
        
        
        for ($i = 1; $i < $QtdeParcelas; $i++) {
            //agora dentro do array queri inserir os próximos vencimentos     incrementando de 30 em 30 dias
            $array['data'][] = date('Y-m-d', strtotime('+30 days', strtotime($array['data'][$i - 1])));
            $array['valor'][] = $val_parcela;
        }
    } else {
        //caso haja apenas uma parcela a mesma é inserida no array e retornada
        $array[] = $DataPrimeira;
        $array['valor'][] = $ValorTotal;
    }
    
    
    
    return $array;
}
```

Utilização:

```
$resultado = DesdobraParcelas(200.00, 2, '2016-12-15');

echo '<pre>';
var_dump($resultado);
echo '</pre>';
```

Resultado:

> array(2) {
>
> ["data"]=>
>
> array(2) {
>
> ```
> [0]=>
>
> string(10) "2016-12-15"
>
> [1]=>
>
> string(10) "2017-01-14"
> ```
>
> }
>
> ["valor"]=>
>
> array(2) {
>
> ```
> [0]=>
>
> float(100)
>
> [1]=>
>
> float(100)
> ```
>
> }
>
> }

Comment: Muito obrigado @AllanAndrade era exatamente o que eu precisava inclusive os valores.

Answer (score 2):

Pela questão inicial, me pareceu que sua variável `$ValorTotal` não tem uso dentro da função, então deixei apenas o cálculo das datas, que é mais simples. Seria interessante também você ter a quantidade de dias como um parâmetro da função.

```
function DesdobraParcelas($QtdeParcelas, $DataPrimeira) 
{
   $array = array();
   $DataParcela = $DataPrimeira;
   for($i = 0; $i < $QtdeParcelas; $i++) { 
      if ($i > 0) {
          $DataParcela = date('Y-m-d', strtotime('+30 days', $DataParcela));
      }
      $array[] = $DataParcela;
   }
   return $array; 
}
```

Para dividir o valor em parcelas é mais complicado e precisa entender os critérios que vai usar. Precisa cuidar com centavos porque a soma das parcelas deve ser igual ao valor total e por isso você não pode fazer uma divisão simples de `Total / Quantidade`. Quando isso acontece uma das parcelas também ficará com valor maior e você precisa ter um critério para decidir se ela ficará como primeira ou como última parcela.

Answer (score 2):

Aqui está minha solução usando as classes `DateTime` e `DateInterval`

```
function parcelas($total, $quantidadeParcelas, $vencimento)
{
        if ($quantidadeParcelas > 1) {
        $dados = array();

        $valorParcelas = $total / $quantidadeParcelas;
        $pagamento = new DateTime($vencimento);
        $dados[$pagamento->format('d-m-Y')] = $valorParcelas;

        for ($i=1; $i < $quantidadeParcelas; $i++) {
            $dados[$pagamento->add(new DateInterval('P30D'))->format('d/m/Y')] = $valorParcelas;
        }

        return $dados;
    }
}

var_dump(parcelas(100, 3, '09-01-2017'));

array(3) {
  ["09-01-2017"]=>
     float(33.333333333333)
  ["08/02/2017"]=>
     float(33.333333333333)
  ["10/03/2017"]=>
     float(33.333333333333)
}
```

Comment: Obrigado @RafaelAcioly ainda não trabalhei com DateInterval pela sua dica vou estudar a documentação.